# How to add image in dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to design my pop up alert dialog like in the picture below.
[image]

However, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it. I got errors like below when I try to add the image...

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/images/icons8-easy.png)
```

Below is my code so far:

```
showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                                title: null,
                                content: Container(
                                  height: 100.h,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        width: 100.w,
                                        child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons8-easy.png"),)
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width: size.width * 0.8,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Success",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'HelveticaNueue',
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16.sp,
                                              height: 1.5.h),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        )),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )

                              ));
```

and here is my pubspec file

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/Dialogflowservice/
```

Comment: did you add the asset path in pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: @M.M.Hasibuzzaman yes... I'm still new with flutter and the internet provide little code example that include image in pop up dialog

Comment: can i see the code you have already tried?

Comment: @M.M.Hasibuzzaman Yeah, I've just added my code... sorry if it seems like a noob code, ahah I'm new to designing dialog and I'm trying to learn as I go. I'm trying to design it as in the picture.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong though, give the container height. And you can also do a clean rebuild of the project,

Comment: I tried doing a different image and it work... I guess the image that I want just does not want to comply with my request lol @M.M.Hasibuzzaman

Comment: That is unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

it is the same as in any other widget. you just have to add a column to your dialog and add inside the widget of the image.

Also make sure you have added your asset in your pubspec.

Comment: If you see the code I have just added, I tried doing exactly just that :(

Comment: just added it @Jennsen

Comment: After add your image to the folder, Did you do a full restart to your app?

Comment: I did everything... I guess the image just does not want to comply with my request. I tried with other image and everything works fine lol

Comment: Glad it works for you now, even with another image 